# HandsonTable sort data by loading from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, handsontable

I try to use Handsontable plugin and want to sort data on table by using ajax .

When I use `columnSorting: true`, there only sorting on view and I update it goes wrong index row.

Anyone has idea how to sort data from php and then show data result after sort on table?

```
$container.handsontable({ 
  colHeaders: header(),//["Title", "Description", "Comments"],
  data : data(),
  //startRows: 3,
  columnSorting: true,
  startCols: 20,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  minSpareRows: 1,
  contextMenu: true,
  copyRowsLimit: 100000,
  beforeChange: function (change, source) {
    if (source === 'loadData') {
        return; //don't save this change
    }
    if ($('input[name=autosave]').is(':checked')) {
        $("#dataconsole").html("<p>Please wait ...</p>").hide().fadeIn("slow"); 
      clearTimeout(autosaveNotification);
      $.ajax({
        url: "../php/save_auto.php?cmid=<?php echo $com_id;?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"changes": change}, //contains changed cells' data
        success: function (data) {
          $("#dataconsole").text('Autosaved (' + change.length + ' cell' + (change.length > 1 ? 's' : '') + ')');
          if(source !== 'program'){
            // reset current cell
            $( "td:contains('=')").text(data);
          } 
        }//complete
      });
    }//checked
  }//change
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is disable the sorting plugin and on click of the header, send a request to your backend with the data and the sorting parameter. Do whatever sorting you want in there, then return the new `data` object and `updateSettings` on your `hotInstance` like so:

```
hotInstance.updateSettings({
    data: newData
})
```

And with this you should be set to go.

Comment: but . how can i get whick colum to sort ?

Comment: Just check what the value of the header you clicked on is. Depends how you're activating that click event.